# In particular vs Typically

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference, word-meaning, word-difference

I heard so many sentences that are begun with 'Typically' or 'In particular' while I do not even know what the exact meaning of them is.

What are simply the differences between these sentences below?

> **Typically**, mouse needs more physical space
>
> **In particular**, mouse needs more physical space

Lots of thanks.

Comment: Michael: Have you searched dictionaries for the meanings of these words? Please provide the definitions you find and let us know that you still need help understanding what you find. Here is some help about what kind of questions to ask and how to ask them: http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, Jim. Yes, I have checked the dictionary and understand the meaning of these words, but I do not understand the EXACT meaning, the differences of how to use these words, which of them is more appropriate in certain sentence, etc. The point is, I just want to know what are the differences(if any) on these two sentences above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> **Typically**, *a* mouse needs more physical space.

Here *typically* means *most of the time* or *usually*

But in

> **In particular**, *a* mouse needs more physical space.

*in particular* means *specifically*. You are pointing out the importance of this condition compared with others mentioned (in context outside of this statement).

Comment: Thanks! _Specifically_ is the most suitable explication. Now it's really clear

Answer (score 0):

The first one means *Usually* or *most often*:

> Mice usually need more space.

The second one means *compared to (something)*:

> Mice, **more than other animals,** need more space.

So, mice, compared to something. Maybe more than other lab animals. Maybe more than other mammals, etc.